# Is it possible to run UI Tests on travis-ci (possible with different simulator types - iPhone 4/5/6, iPad etc)

Tags: travis-ci, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

If yes what are the limits? Is it possible to run them in parallel?

Comment: Yes; read the docs; yes.

Comment: would you be so nice to provide a link here? I can't find any mention in docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not work with travis, but

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/109418/travis-ci-tutorial
2. as i see [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/) they offer to use xctool, but it is not support XC UI
3. i think you can use [scan](https://github.com/fastlane/scan/)  inside your travis scripts. This utillity provides report in junit format.